# ormlite ,must i use @DatabaseField(useGetSet=true) to accessed with each field get and set methods

Tags: android, annotations, default, ormlite

I an new in ormlite.

useGetSet:

Boolean that says that the field should be accessed with get and set methods.
Default is false which instead uses direct field access via Java re
ection. This
may be necessary if the object you are storing has protections around it.
NOTE: The name of the get method must match getXxx() where Xxx is the
name of the field with the first letter capitalized. The get must return a class
which matches the field's exactly. The set method must match setXxx(), have
a single argument whose class matches the field's exactly, and return void. For
example:

```
@DatabaseField(useGetSet = true)
private Integer orderCount;
public Integer getOrderCount() {
   return orderCount;
}
public void setOrderCount(Integer orderCount) {
   this.orderCount = orderCount;
}
```

you can see Default is false which instead uses direct field access via Java re
ection.

My question is how to set default is ture(i do not want to write @DatabaseField(useGetSet = true) many times)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately is not possible to change de default value of an @interface field. But I suggest you to don't use useGetSet = true unless you do extra stuff in the setter or getter. The default behaivor is better in most cases.